# Can't multiply width in \newcommand for includegraphics

Tags: macros, includegraphics

Minimal example, multiplying by 0.5 makes the command fail :

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\dontwork}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.5*(#1)\textwidth]{frog.jpg}}
\newcommand{\work}[1]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{frog.jpg}}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
    \dontwork{1}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get this error :
[image: Here is my error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\dimexpr` (provided by the e-TeX extensions whose availability is standard in LaTeX nowadays):

`\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr.5\textwidth*(#1)\relax]{frog.jpg}`

Be aware that in case of multiplication the formal syntax of `\dimexpr` requires the dimension to come first and the scaling-factor to come last, nested in parentheses in case it is formed by a numerical expression. E.g.,
`\dimexpr(.5\textwidth)*(#1)\relax`
does work if `#1` forms a valid numerical expression while
`\dimexpr(#1)*(.5\textwidth)\relax`
does not.

If `#1` shall not necessarily be an integer, then scale the `\dimexpr` itself:

`\includegraphics[width=#1\dimexpr.5\textwidth\relax]{frog.jpg}`
or
`\includegraphics[width=.5\dimexpr#1\textwidth\relax]{frog.jpg}`

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
  \includegraphics[width=#1\dimexpr0.5\textwidth\relax]{...}
```

Alhough specifying a fraction of half `\textwidth` seems a very weird interface, are you wanting a fraction of `\columnwidth` ??

Comment: In my use case I multiply by `0.77` to suit the beamer height

Comment: @Butanium still seems strange to me, why not scale by height rather than width if height is the  limiting dimension?

Comment: it'll be easier to give you my use case directly : `\newcommand{\adaptgraphics}[2][1]{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth,height=#1\dimexpr0.77\textheight,keepaspectratio]{figures/#2}}
`

Comment: @Butanium OK:-)

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on a latex discord :

```latex
\newcommand{\flatfrog}[1]{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr 0.33\textwidth*(#1)\relax]{frog.jpg}}
```

Works, `\dimexpr` makes the evaluation preserving the dimension of `\textwidth` which is needed